# Combine OnIdiom and OnOrientation

Tags: xaml, responsive-design, maui

I want to use OnIdiom in combination with [OnOrientation](https://www.cayas.de/de/blog/responsive-layouts-for-dotnet-maui) so that I can specify four distinct sets of row heights in my grid.  In other words, I want unique styles for [Portrait Phone], [Landscape Phone], [Portrait Tablet] and [Landscape Tablet].  I tried this...

```
  <Grid 
        ColumnDefinitions="0.5*,0.5*" RowSpacing="20"        
          RowDefinitions="{OnIdiom 
              Default= {helper:OnOrientation Default='40,40,*,150,40', Landscape='80,100,*,100,40', TypeConverter={x:Type RowDefinitionCollectionTypeConverter}}, Phone= {helper:OnOrientation Default='40,40,*,150,40', Landscape='40,0,*,100,40', TypeConverter={x:Type RowDefinitionCollectionTypeConverter}}}">
      <Grid
```

... and it seemed to work!  But it looks like it works correctly only in Debug.  When I deployed a release build to my Android phone the row heights were wrong.  I don't mean that Maui picked the wrong style from my definitions.  I mean that it set some other weird style that I never specified.

I'm a bit surprised that I can't find more info on this.  The real estate of a landscape tablet is as different from a landscape phone as a portrait phone is from a landscape phone.

Comment: Use explicit assignment if you are facing issues that's the only way, or you could make changes to them in the CS file instead of XAML (Not sure why people think this breaks Mvvm principles because it doesn't you're making changes in the same class but just using partials)

Comment: Thanks, but what would explicit assignment look like (pardon my ignorance)?